# Can't use a variable out of while and pipe in bash

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, pipe

I have a code like that

```
var="before"  
echo "$someString" | sed '$someRegex' | while read line 
do
    if [ $condition ]; then
        var="after"
        echo "$var" #first echo
    fi 
done 
echo "$var" #second echo
```

Here first echo print "after", but second is "before". How can I make second echo print "after". I think it is because of pipe buy I don't know how figure out.

Thanks for any solutions...

answer edit:

I corrected it and it works fine. Thanks eugene for your useful answer

```
var="before"  
while read line 
do
    if [ $condition ]; then
        var="after"
        echo "$var" #first echo
    fi 
done < <(echo "$someString" | sed '$someRegex')
echo "$var" #second echo
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is that a `while` loop runs in a subshell when it's part of a pipeline. For the `while` loop above, a new subshell with its own copy of the variable `var` is created.

See this article for possible workarounds: [I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).