# Why is array size not increased while looping?

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm wondering why this code is not working as expected:

```
a=(1)
echo "1 2 3 4" | while read f; do
    a+=("$f")
done
echo "${a[@]}"
```

Output is "1" and not "1 1 2 3 4" as I thought it would be. Any ideas?

Comment: ... and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572411/cant-use-a-variable-out-of-while-and-pipe-in-bash

Comment: your while loop is redundant, there is only one value, which is "1 2 3 4".   Replace array concat with `echo $f` to verify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a pipe, you create a sub shell. The `a` array is correct modified, but only in the sub shell which exits before you print the contents of `a` after the loop.

Solution, use process substitution or a here string instead of a pipe:

```
a=(1)
# this only loops once since there is only one line...
while read f; do    
    a+=("$f")
done < <(echo "1 2 3 4")    # < <(process substitution)
echo "${a[@]}"
# 1 1 2 3 4
```

As a side note, use `declare -p a` instead of `echo "${a[@]}"` to see the contents of an array in Bash if you also want to see the indices.

Here is a better example of what you are seeing:

```
#!/bin/bash
lines=("Top")
echo "Line 1
Line 2
Line 3" | while read -r line; do
    lines+=("$line")
    declare -p lines
done 
declare -p lines
```

Prints:

```
declare -a lines=([0]="Top" [1]="Line 1")
declare -a lines=([0]="Top" [1]="Line 1" [2]="Line 2")
declare -a lines=([0]="Top" [1]="Line 1" [2]="Line 2" [3]="Line 3")
declare -a lines=([0]="Top")
```

Note that `lines` reverts to only one entry after the pipeline. Vs:

```
lines=("Top")
while read -r line; do
    lines+=("$line")
    declare -p lines
done < <(echo "Line 1
Line 2
Line 3")
declare -p lines
```

Prints:

```
declare -a lines=([0]="Top" [1]="Line 1")
declare -a lines=([0]="Top" [1]="Line 1" [2]="Line 2")
declare -a lines=([0]="Top" [1]="Line 1" [2]="Line 2" [3]="Line 3")
declare -a lines=([0]="Top" [1]="Line 1" [2]="Line 2" [3]="Line 3")
```